# Only select a specific page that has been liked or disliked?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables to store peoples interests with likes and dislikes: `pages`, `pages_likes`, `pages_dislikes`

Now I wanted to have a main page to show a random page, but only those that haven't been liked or disliked by the user.

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT p.id AS page_id, d.uid AS duid, l.uid AS luid, p.title FROM pages p 
JOIN pages_dislikes d on d.page_id = p.id JOIN pages_likes l on l.page_id = p.id 
WHERE d.uid != '3' AND l.uid != '3'  ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

But this still shows a page that has been liked or disliked, because there are other users liked or disliked the page like this:

[image]

How could I only show pages a specific user id hasn't liked or disliked yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS page_id
    ,d.uid AS duid
    ,l.uid AS luid
    ,p.title FROM pages p 
LEFT JOIN pages_dislikes d on d.page_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN pages_likes l on l.page_id = p.id 
WHERE (d.page_id IS null OR l.page_id is null) AND d.uid != '3' AND l.uid != '3'
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

You can also try this query:

```
SELECT P.pageid, P.pagename FROM Pages P LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT pageid FROM lik WHERE uid <> 3
    UNION 
    SELECT pageid FROM dis WHERE uid <> 3
) LikesDislikes ON LikesDislikes.pageid = P.pageid
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be null, I want to exclude just one specific user-id (uid), like user-id 3 in my example

Comment: actually it should be page_id. now you can add whatever condition you want.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit before. Well, now I don't get any results at all, even if a page hasn't been liked or disliked yet

Comment: Try first running the query without where condition. See what you get and the no or rows you get. then check with the condition where page_id is being tested for null and so proceed on.

Comment: Logic would be to first get all the pages which haven't been liked and disliked. Then filter the resutl on the basis of user.

Comment: I tried it this way, but I can't figure out the right logic to filter the result I want to get. I also don't know why page_id has to be null?

Comment: To find out if a page has been liked or not you left join all the rows in likes and dislikes table with pages table. this gives you all the data in the pages and those matching rows in likes and dislikes. where there is no match page_id would be null meaning those pages haven't been liked or disliked. then you further filter on the users.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I don't know why I get wrong results.  Shouldn't I create a sort of subquery to select all disliked and liked page ids of a specific user id and exclude them then?

Comment: I posted an updated query. You can try that. I am pretty sure would always work.